# Execution of postfix ++ operation

Tags: javascript, c#, postfix-operator

How does a postfix ++ operator works :

```
var a = 100;
var b = a++ + a;
//Result 201
```

Here if 'a' is incremented then should not the value be 202. And if it is true then should not be the next equation value 301 ?

```
var a = 100;
var b = a++ + a + a;
//Result 302
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
var a = 100;
var b = a++ + a;
```

what happens is:

1. `a` is set to `100`
2. `a++` is evaluated. The value of that subexpression is `100`. Also, `a` is set to `101`.
3. The value of `a` (`101`) is added to the value of the left-hand subexpression (`100`).
4. `b` is set to the result, `201`.

The postfix `++` operator returns the value of the variable as it was *before* the increment. The *prefix* `++` operator (as in `++a`) performs the increment and gives the value *after* that.

The behavior in JavaScript is the same as in many other languages with expression syntax and semantics derived from C.

Comment: very nice explanation (+1) from me.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix means get value first and then increment.

Your result is

```
 100 (add one to a) + 101
```